# Why does the ansible remote copy not work from local

Tags: linux, copy, ansible

I just started learning ansible and writing first `copy` module but i am clueless why its not working.

```
---
 - hosts: osa
   tasks:
     - name: Copying file to remote host
       copy: src=/tmp/foo.txt dest=/tmp/bar.txt
```

Ran playbook but nothing happened and no error too.

```
# /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /home/spatel/ansible/first-playbook.yml

PLAY [osa] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.5.1.160]

TASK [Copying file to remote host] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.5.1.160]

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.5.1.160                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

My /etc/ansible/hosts file has **Remote** host IP address:

```
[osa]
10.5.1.160
```

Verbose output:

```
# ansible-playbook -vv first-playbook.yml
ansible-playbook 2.4.1.0
  config file = /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/root/.ansible/plugins/modules', u'/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/bin/ansible-playbook
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)]
Using /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg as config file

PLAYBOOK: first-playbook.yml ********************************************************************************************************************************************************
1 plays in first-playbook.yml

PLAY [osa] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
META: ran handlers

TASK [Copying file to remote host] **************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /home/spatel/ansible/first-playbook.yml:5
ok: [10.5.1.160] => {"changed": false, "checksum": "4383f040dc0303e55260bca327cc0eeb213b04b5", "failed": false, "gid": 0, "group": "root", "mode": "0644", "owner": "root", "path": "/tmp/bar.txt", "secontext": "unconfined_u:object_r:admin_home_t:s0", "size": 8, "state": "file", "uid": 0}
META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY RECAP **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
10.5.1.160                 : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

## UPDATE

I have noticed its copying file to localhost **not** remote host, this makes no sense, why is it saying in the output that it is executing the playbook on the remote host (10.5.1.160) ?????

```
# ls -l /tmp/bar.txt
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 16 May 24 10:45 /tmp/bar.txt
```

Comment: It looks as if the file would already exist on the server!? Try adding `-v` / `-vvv` to the ansible call - does this all look plausible?

Comment: why negative mark on question, do you think this is a silly question? Believe me i test everything nothing is on remote host.

Comment: Is localhost and 'osa' the same host?

Comment: Don't be discouraged by a downvote. It could mean any of a lot of things, including someone just being pissy -- but your best bet is to rewrite your question according to [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), which will more likely get a good answer sooner. Downvotes are usually an indication that your question is lacking some relevant info, or is otherwise somehow difficult to parse and answer without some editing. I use `-vv` as a standard. one to four v's will give you increasing amounts of debugging output, to the point of drowning you in it. Try it - it's worth it.

Comment: `osa` with 10.5.1.161 IP address, If i run simple playbook doing touch is remote machine /bin/touch it works but `copy` doesn't i am clue less.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem that it was looking for a file on the remote server. You are running your tasks on remote server `hosts: osa` but the file is on localhost. I could solve it with **delegate_to: localhost**.

```
---
 - hosts: osa
   tasks:
     - name: Copying file to remote host
       delegate_to: localhost
       copy: src=/tmp/foo.txt dest=/tmp/bar.txt
```

However, I had to make even first a task to get the file from localhost and then to provide it afterwards to the remote host:

```
  - name: read files

    # This needs to run on localhost, because that's where
    # the keys are stored.
    delegate_to: localhost

    command: cat {{item}}

    # Register the results of this task in a variable called
    # "files"
    register: files

    with_fileglob:
      - "/tmp/*.txt"

  - name: show what was stored in the files variable
    debug:
      var: files

  - name: Copying file to remote host
     delegate_to: localhost
     copy: src="{{item.stdout}}" dest=/tmp/bar.txt
    with_items: "{{keys.results}}"
```